# Accessing a HtmlGenericControl on a MasterPage from a ContentPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, controls, htmlgenericcontrol

so I've got the following structures;

**Start.master (Start.master.cs)**

Contains a Method

```
DoSomething(string Text)
{
    _MyHtmlControl.InnerText = Text;  
}
```

And the HtmlGenericControl ID'ed *_MyHtmlControl*

**Page.aspx (Page.aspx.cs)**

Calls the Method via `new Start().DoSomething("Test");`

Doing so gives me the following error: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

How can I make it work, so I can call `DoSomething()` and it writes the given string into the HtmlGenericControl that is defined in the MasterPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[ASP.Net Master Pages: Tips, Tricks, and Traps](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)

> **Abstract Interaction**
>
> Now it’s time to have the master page
>   and content page interact. There are
>   different approaches we can take to
>   achieve interaction, but the best
>   approaches are the ones that use the
>   master page for what it is: a user
>   control.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how come you never find such useful sites when searching by your own? -.-"